# Unity: Changing velocity of RigidBody2D after collision causes game to crash regardless of platform, including in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This line of code is single handedly causing my game to crash only sometimes. It essentially freezes the editor and I have to force quit Unity, and same on mobile.

```
_rb.velocity = new Vector2(_rb.velocity.x, -20f);
```

I've tried setting a flag in the collision and updating velocity on the next fixed update. I've tried updating the velocity directly in the EnterCollision2D method.

Notably I haven't been able to recreate the crash when applying force instead of altering velocity, but applying force doesn't give the desired effect.

The editor logs don't have anything in them either, so I'm pretty confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Questions about debugging require enough information to reproduce the problem. For unity questions, this includes steps to create a minimally necessary scene, hierarchy, and components, as well as minimally necessary code. See [mre] and [ask] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the collision isnt the poroblem here. Make sure you don't have any infinite loops in your code (calling the same method inside of the method or using while loops outside of coroutines). Also if you are using unity 2018 it tends to crash quite fast.

Comment: I'm using 2019. It actually would crash when adding force too after a bit. So far It seems to MAYBE be fixed by adding custom physics materials to each of the objects. I have no while loops in my code and no infinite loops.